# NUnit3TestExecutor converted 279 of 279 NUnit test cases

Tags: nunit-3.0

I get `NUnit3TestExecutor converted 279 of 279 NUnit test cases` in the output when I compile. Why?
I suppose the solution has been upgraded once from 2 to 3 but that is about all of a clue I have.

I have checked we only use Nunit version 3.
279 is just a few of all the tests we have.

**UPDATE**

Digging into [`NUnit3TestExecutor`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/master/src/NUnitTestAdapter/NUnit3TestExecutor.cs) I find

```
private void RunAssembly(string assemblyName, TestFilter filter) {
    ...
    var nunitTestCases = loadResult.SelectNodes("//test-case");
    ...
    foreach (XmlNode testNode in nunitTestCases){
        loadedTestCases.Add(testConverter.ConvertTestCase(testNode));
    }
    TestLog.Info(string.Format("NUnit3TestExecutor converted {0} of {1} NUnit test cases", loadedTestCases.Count, nunitTestCases.Count));
    ...
}
```

`ConvertTestCase` looks like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an NUnit test into a TestCase for Visual Studio,
    /// using the best method available according to the exact
    /// type passed and caching results for efficiency.
    /// </summary>
    public TestCase ConvertTestCase(XmlNode testNode)
```

which is the culprit.

Which seems correct since we have Nunit tests running inside Visualstudio. But... we don't have 279 `[TestFixture]` or `[Test]`. There is something more at play.
So I am still in limbo.

Comment: Hi LosManos. Any updates?

May I suggest you ask a specific question? No offence intended. It just isn't clear to me whether you are questioning the number of "converted" tests or the fact that any tests are converted at all.

Comment: No offence taken, your remark is valid. I wonder what the difference is between the tests that trigger the message and the tests that don't. Say I have 1000 tests and 279 of then need to be converted; which and why?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no answer. I arrived at this question because I was questioning whether I should see the "converted...test cases" at all. I've concluded the message is no cause for (my) concern.

Comment: I suppose I should explain my prior comment. I noticed the "converted...test cases" message after converting an application to NUnit from MSTest (Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework). I was concerned that that the message might signify something wrong with my conversion. I decided the "converted...test cases" is nothing to worry about after also seeing it in other presumed "good applications" - that used NUnit.

Answer (score 3):

That "NUnit3TestExecutor converted x of x NUnit test cases" log comes from [this code](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/fbf83acd7e4ffb1f5fbb6bae71070a98ed9429bd/src/NUnitTestAdapter/NUnit3TestExecutor.cs#L257), which is calling the [ConvertTestCase method here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/7b332ff922ae606a7c1fb4838e9758c16eddc64b/src/NUnitTestAdapter/TestConverter.cs#L78).

The documentation on that method says

> Converts an NUnit test into a TestCase for Visual Studio,
>   using the best method available according to the exact
>   type passed and caching results for efficiency.

So it seems that it's not about what version of NUnit you have, but just converting the tests into a format that Visual Studio understands.